# Como Mostrar una Imagen en Ventana Modal Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap

Tengo una tabla donde guardo 6 datos entre ellos un campo donde se guarda la ruta de una imagen guardada en el servidor.

Tengo un botón dentro de la pagina llamado detalles donde al darle clic muestra una ventana modal con la información de este, pero no se como mostrar la imagen que se guardo en la base de datos solo me muestra el nombre de la imagen.

Comment: Podías poner el código que usas con el botón y el html, de la ventana modal

Comment: Enseñanos el código que tienes para ayudarte más claranente.

Comment: revisa la ruta que le pones a la imagen... prueba usando una imagen que tengas descargada y usando su dirección o que la dirección que usas del archivo termine con una extensión de gráfico .png .jpg, etc

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que usas bootstrap 3 (deberi funcionar similar en 2 y 1), entonces, basta con incluir dentro del body del modal una etiqueta html de imagenes 'img' y por javascript o php (lo dejo a tu elección) asignas la ruta de la imagen en la porpiedad 'src', un ejemplo sencillo sería como:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">  
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">      
        <div class="modal-header">        
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>        
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>      </div>      
        <div class="modal-body"><img src="http://static.batanga.com/sites/default/files/styles/full/public/universo-observable-en-una-imagen-3.png?itok=sBpiT7gx" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236" />   </div>      
        <div class="modal-footer">        
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>     
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente código (PHP)

```
<img src="<?php echo $ruta; ?> ">
```

de otra forma (JS)

```
<img src=ruta>
```